# How to fix the Error type 13 on my VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, vba

I Have This VBA code on Excel. When I execute it I have this error "Erreur 13: Incompatibilité de type".

Vlookup is applying in between 2 workbooks.

`Range("A2:232")` contains date type and `Cells(i,Lcol-4)` too

Please Help.

This is my code

```
    If Application.Vlookup(Cells(i,Lcol-4), Workbooks("V_TAUX.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A2:232"),1,False) = Cells(i,Lcol-4) Then
        Instruction...
        Instruction....
    End If
```

Comment: `Workbooks("V_TAUX.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A2:232")` - should that read `"A2:A32"` instead?  Or `"A2:A232"`?  Is that error in the actual code, or just in the question?  (Also, you might want to put the VLOOKUP into a `Variant` first, so you can test if it `IsError`, when `ActiveSheet.Cells(i,Lcol-4).Value` is not in `Workbooks("V_TAUX.xlsx").Sheets(1).Columns("A")`)

Comment: Also, `VLOOKUP` seems a very inefficient way to do this - have you considered `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks("V_TAUX.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A2:A32"), Cells(i,Lcol-4)) > 0 Then` instead?

Answer (score 0):

`Cells(i,Lcol-4)` or the equivalent `Cells(i,Lcol-4).Value` returns a Date type value, whereas the dates listed in your worksheet are actually serial numbers formatted as dates.

As a result, VLookup won't be able to return a match.  And, since you've qualified your reference with Application, instead of WorksheetFunction, it returns a non-breaking error.

However, since the error returned by VLookup is being compared with the value in `Cells(i,Lcol-4)`, you'll get a type mismatch breaking error.

So, first I would suggest that you convert your lookup value to a Long data type...

```
 Application.Vlookup(CLng(Cells(i,Lcol-4).Value), . . .
```

Then, as already suggested by Chronocidal, assign the return value to a Variant so that you can use IsError to check for an error...

```
Dim matchVal As Variant

matchVal = Application.VLookup(CLng(Cells(i, Lcol - 4).Value), Workbooks("V_TAUX.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A2:A232"), 1, False)

If Not IsError(matchVal) Then
    'etc
    '
    '
End If
```

Although, since you're simply checking for a match, you can use Application.Match instead...

```
Dim matchVal As Variant

matchVal = Application.Match(CLng(Cells(i, Lcol - 4).Value), Workbooks("V_TAUX.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A2:A232"), 0)

If Not IsError(matchVal) Then
    'etc
    '
    '
End If
```